# Reference manager for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, latex, citations

I'm in dire need of a reference/citation manager in Ubuntu.  The features I need the most are:

1) Metadata extraction/editing of pdf
2) Fetch metadata from online databases such as Google Scholar
3) Attach pdf or other file to reference
4) Tag references and recall those with a given tag or set of tags
5) Provide APA style citation for references (in integration with OOffice and/or Latex)

Optional: Would be great if it can annotate/highlight pdfs.

Mendeley probably does all of these, but it's behavior has driven me insane, especially when the number of references it's trying to handle is large. It constantly tries to sync with the web and creates duplicate references.

I've tried JabRef, and while it looks like a decent piece of freeware, it doesn't do some of the above. I found others like Bibus, Referencer, etc. to be lacking or buggy or inactive development.

Is there another option, or should I give up the search.

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting metadata could be to use [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/); export to .bib, and import into jabref. [Bibdesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/) does much of what you require, but is Mac only, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Zotero, you can also directly export any collection of references to a bibTeX file, or simply ctrl-select a number of references and right-click export, etc.